# Create a Ray from two points

Tags: geometry

I know it's too easy for this website but I couldn't think of it myself.
I have a point A(x1,y1,z1) and another point B(x2,y2,z2). And I represent a ray like this : r(t) = o + t *d.
Using the given ray and point notation, how can I represent a ray whose start point is A and going through point B.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A+t(B-A)$, $B$ is at $t=1$............................